# How to extract IP addresses from a file if listed more than X times

Tags: text-processing

I would like to extract IP addresses that meet the requirements of

1. Containing foo
2. Listed in the file more than 5 times

Example of my log below

```
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31385#31385: *4283 limiting requests, excess: 100.110 by zone "foo", client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31386#31386: *4107 limiting requests, excess: 100.962 by zone "bar", client: 1.1.1.2, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31386#31386: *4107 limiting requests, excess: 100.962 by zone "bar", client: 1.1.1.2, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31385#31385: *4164 limiting requests, excess: 100.102 by zone "foo", client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31386#31386: *4107 limiting requests, excess: 100.962 by zone "bar", client: 1.1.1.2, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31384#31384: *2404 limiting requests, excess: 100.080 by zone "foo", client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31386#31386: *4107 limiting requests, excess: 100.962 by zone "bar", client: 1.1.1.2, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31384#31384: *2321 limiting requests, excess: 100.062 by zone "foo", client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31386#31386: *4107 limiting requests, excess: 100.962 by zone "bar", client: 1.1.1.2, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31386#31386: *4220 limiting requests, excess: 100.020 by zone "foo", client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31385#31385: *4406 limiting requests, excess: 100.002 by zone "foo", client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31376#31376: *4172 limiting requests, excess: 100.996 by zone "foo", client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31386#31386: *4190 limiting requests, excess: 100.988 by zone "foo", client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31376#31376: *2549 limiting requests, excess: 100.984 by zone "foo", client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31386#31386: *4189 limiting requests, excess: 100.972 by zone "foo", client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31386#31386: *4107 limiting requests, excess: 100.962 by zone "bar", client: 1.1.1.2, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31386#31386: *4107 limiting requests, excess: 100.962 by zone "bar", client: 1.1.1.2, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
2020/12/07 03:25:16 [error] 31386#31386: *4107 limiting requests, excess: 100.962 by zone "foo", client: 1.1.1.1, server: example.com, request: "POST /some-link HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/some-link"
```

The result should be an output of

```
1.1.1.1
```

1.1.1.2 should not be printed because it was not part of the `foo` zone

I have been able to list how many times each IP gets listed by

```
grep -o "[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+" testfile | sort | uniq -c
     11 1.1.1.1
      7 1.1.1.2
```

But I am not sure how to require `foo` and then write the IPs listed more than 5 times to a file

Comment: We need to see what you've tried already - as it currently stands you have information you want done but we are not a code writing service and would prefer to see what you've tried first.

Comment: I updated my question, that's all I have been able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
gawk '
  /zone "foo"/ && match($0, /client: ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/,m) {
    count[m[1]]++
  } 
  END {
    for (client in count) {if (count[client] > 5) print client}
  }
' testfile
```

Alternatively using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (this is more specific in that it treats the entries as delimited `key: value` pairs and restricts the matches to the named fields `excess` and `client` respectively)

```
mlr --dkvp --fs ', ' --ps ': ' \
  filter '$excess =~ "zone \"foo\""' then \
  put -q '@count[$client] += 1; end {for (client in @count) {if (@count[client] > 5){print client}}}
' testfile
```

Comment: Thank you this works great. I was hoping for a $ output so I can add text easily to the front/end. How could I make this so it would change the output to 'deny 1.1.1.1;'

Comment: @BlahBlah you can easily do that in either awk (`print "deny", client`) or Miller (`print "deny " . client`)

Comment: Could you also include ipv6? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421519/how-to-extract-ipv6-addresses-from-a-file - Do I just add | 'ipv6 code' after [0-9]+)/,m) ?

Comment: @BlahBlah I don't know, since your data doesn't include any IPv6 addresses. You can *probably* just capture everything up to the comma `/client: ([^,]+)/` which will make it agnostic (as the Miller version already is).

Answer (score 0):

I change you're command line to get each line and separate argument with cut
after that, I just have to check if the first field is greater than 4

one line exemple

```
while read -r proc; do val=`echo "$proc" | cut -d' ' -f1 `; ip=`echo $proc | cut -d' ' -f2`; if [ $val -gt 4 ]; then echo $ip; fi ; done <<< `grep -o "[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+" ipList.txt | sort | uniq -c`
```

multi-line for more understanding syntaxe:

```
while read -r proc
do
    val=`echo "$proc" | cut -d' ' -f1 `
    ip=`echo $proc | cut -d' ' -f2`
    if [ $val -gt 4 ]
    then
        echo $ip
    fi
done <<< `grep -o "[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+" ipList.txt | sort | uniq -c`
```

Comment: This will work with other values that are not "foo"

Comment: Sorry, i miss this part of you're post 
maybe the same solution with some change in the grep command will work.
The anwer of steeldriver seem better that mine